# Конструктор копии возвращает некорректные данные

Tags: c++, mingw

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class myclass {
public:
    int var;
    myclass(int i) { cout << "Obuchnuy konstructor.\n"; var = i; }
    myclass(const myclass &obj) { cout << "Konstructor kopii.\n"; cout << "Kk: " << obj.var << endl; }
    ~myclass() { cout << "Destructor.\n"; }
};

myclass f()
{
    myclass ob(5);
    cout << ob.var << endl;
    return ob;
}

int main()
{
    myclass a(10);
    cout << a.var << endl;
    a = f();
    cout << a.var << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод MVS 2013:

```
Obuchnuy konstructor.
10
Obuchnuy konstructor.
5
Konstructor kopii.
Kk: 5
Destructor.
Destructor.
-858993460
```

Т.е. конструктор копии вернул в main() "мусор".

Если компилировать с помощью mingw и ключом -fno-elide-constructors(иначе игнорируется конструктор копии) вывод почти такой же, только "мусор" другой.

Вопрос, почему?

Comment: вы же в конструкторе копирования оставили только печать, а самого копирование объекта нет, вот при выходе из функции после вызова конструктора копирования мусор и возвращается.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш конструктор копии не копирует члены данных объекта-аргумента конструктора.

```
myclass(const myclass &obj) { cout << "Konstructor kopii.\n"; cout << "Kk: " << obj.var << endl; }
```

Он только выводит на консоль значение члена данных `var` объекта-аргумента конструктора. Конструктор должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
myclass(const myclass &obj) : var( obj.var ) 
{ 
    cout << "Konstructor kopii.\n"; cout << "Kk: " << obj.var << endl; 
}
```

Обратите внимание, что вам следует явно определить копирующий оператор присваивания. Согласно текущему стандарту C++ (12.8 Copying and moving class objects)

> 18 If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If the class
>   definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator,
>   the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as
>   deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). **The latter
>   case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy constructor
>   or a user-declared destructor**.

Comment: Спасибо, ещё вопрос, можно ли утверждать, что конструктор копии в моей программе вызывается для создания объекта 'a' вот здесь: a = f(); ?

Comment: @Dim Team В этом предложении используется копирующий оператор присваивания, определенный неявно компилятором, так как объект a был уже создан.

Comment: @DimTeam, в этой строчке *может* быть вызван конструктор копирования(если нет конструктора перемещения и NRVO не отработало). После этого будет вызван оператор присваивания(либо копирующий, либо перемещающий(если он переопределён))

Comment: @ixSci В классе нет ни конструктора перемещения, ни оператора перемещения.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, я вижу, но автору полезно это знать, я считаю. Я ведь использовал слов "если".